# Multi Column Vlookup and Place an 'X' where File Name and ID Intersect

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I’m trying to search for a workbook name and find any ID numbers in one of 13 columns, and if there is a match, place an ‘X’ in a cell on another sheet.  Since a picture is worth 1000 words, I’m posting a couple images to illustrate the point.

I have a small UDF that strips out numbers from alpha-numeric cells.  This gives me an ID number.  In a few cases, I do need an alpha-numeric ID, like LQ2.  Anyway, I want to look for these IDs in any row in 13 columns and get the workbook name from the same row.

[image]

Then, I want to match this against the same workbook name in another sheet, and if an ID is found in any of those 13 columns, put an x in the cell where the workbook name and ID intersect.

[image]

I tried to pivot the data, but I couldn't get it working.  I'm thinking that some kind of pivot solution should work.  Either a code solution or a formula solution would be great.  I'm trying to put together a VBA script that, hopefully, will get me close.  I'll post back when I have made more progress on this.

My thanks to all.

Quick update: I tried a double match, like this . . .

```
=MATCH($B2&C$1,'Tasks & Remarks Split'!$Q$2:$AC$966&'Tasks & Remarks Split'!$A$2:$A$966,0)
```

This is CSE-entered.  I thought it would pickup the matches, but it returns all #N/A results.  Something is off here, because I know there are several matches.  Can someone offer a tip?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a sumproduct against 2 criteria and if the count is >0 then put an 'X' in the cell.  It seems to work just fine.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--('Tasks & Remarks Split'!$A$2:$A$966=C$1)*('Tasks & Remarks Split'!$Q$2:$AC$966=$B2))>0,"X","")
```